# Building ASP.Net control from JSON Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working project where I need to build ASP.net control base on JSON data. I am using this method below to get all the data into class. I as using `FirstOrDefault` and the `Where(x => x.Type == ???` to drill down into the data. I think the logic could be simplified, Any suggestions are welcomed. working sample below

JSON data

```json
[
    {
        "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 2,
        "MeetingPollingQuestionType": "LongAnswerText",
        "MeetingPollingId": 3,
        "SequenceOrder": 1,
        "MeetingPollingParts": [
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 2,
                "Type": "Question",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 2,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "label",
                        "QuestionValue": "This is a long question",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
        "MeetingPollingQuestionType": "MultipleChoice",
        "MeetingPollingId": 3,
        "SequenceOrder": 2,
        "MeetingPollingParts": [
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 3,
                "Type": "Question",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "label",
                        "QuestionValue": "this is a multiple choice question",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 4,
                "Type": "Image",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "Image",
                        "QuestionValue": null,
                        "FileManagerId": 14552,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "MeetingPollingPartsId": 5,
                "Type": "Answers",
                "MeetingPollingQuestionId": 3,
                "MeetingPollingPartsValues": [
                    {
                        "Type": "radio",
                        "QuestionValue": "Yes",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "radio",
                        "QuestionValue": "No",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    },
                    {
                        "Type": "radio",
                        "QuestionValue": "Abstain",
                        "FileManagerId": 0,
                        "FileName": null,
                        "FileData": null,
                        "FileType": null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

method creating controls

```
public class LongAnswerText : IMeetingPollingQuestion
    {
        private List<MeetingPollingParts> meetingPollingParts;
        private string label = null;
        private string textbox = null;
        private string type = null;

       
        public LongAnswerText(List<MeetingPollingParts> meetingPollingParts)
        {
           
            this.SequenceOrder = SequenceOrder;
            this.MeetingPollingId = MeetingPollingId;
            this.MeetingPollingQuestionId = MeetingPollingQuestionId;

            this.meetingPollingParts = meetingPollingParts;
            var MeetingPollingPartsValuesLabel = new List<MeetingPollingPartsValues>();
            MeetingPollingPartsValuesLabel = meetingPollingParts.SelectMany(s => s.MeetingPollingPartsValues).ToList();
            var labelControl = MeetingPollingPartsValuesLabel.Where(x=>x.Type=="label").FirstOrDefault();
            var textboxControl = MeetingPollingPartsValuesLabel.Where(x => x.Type == "textbox").FirstOrDefault();
            this.label = LabelControl(string.Format("label_{0}", labelControl.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId), labelControl.QuestionValue);
            this.textbox = TextboxControl(string.Format("label_{0}", labelControl.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId));
        }

        public  string LabelControl(string target, string text){
            return string.Format("@Html.LabelFor('{0}'>{1}</input>",target,text);
        }

        public string TextboxControl(string target) { 
            return string.Format("@Html.TextBoxFor('{0}')",target);
            }
    }
```

Output View

```
<div class="form-group row">
   div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.label_1)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.label_1, new { id = "label_1", @class = "form-control" })
   </div>
</div>
```

fiddle

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net/j6YIPN
```

Comment: Could you please share with us a sample JSON data as well?

Comment: I updated with the same json data

Comment: `.Where(x=>x.Type=="label").FirstOrDefault();` => `.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Type=="label");`

Comment: Am I understand correctly that you do self-assignment here: `this.SequenceOrder = SequenceOrder;`?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: By why do you do that?

Comment: Oh your correct no need to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, there is no need in using `Where` LINQ since  `FirstOrDefault` accepts a predicate that can be used to get the value you need:

```
var labelControl = MeetingPollingPartsValuesLabel.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "label");
```

---

As for the other issues...

```
this.SequenceOrder = SequenceOrder;
this.MeetingPollingId = MeetingPollingId;
this.MeetingPollingQuestionId = MeetingPollingQuestionId;
```

There is no point is assigning a property to itself (unless there is some important logic in the setter but that is even worse and not your case).
You can just delete those lines with no effect.

Similarly there is no reason to assign `null` to all those fields:

```
private string label = null;
private string textbox = null;
private string type = null;
```

They are already `null` by default.

`List<MeetingPollingParts> meetingPollingParts`
This parameter name implies that it is a collection of some parts. However type parameter of the `List` is `MeetingPollingParts` in plural, which means that it is a collection of collections of parts. `MeetingPollingParts` should be named `MeetingPollingPart` since it represents a singular part. Such small naming mistakes make the code much harder to read. Please pay attention to them.

Methods `LabelControl` and `TextboxControl` don't use the instance of `LongAnswerText` whose member methods they are, therefore there is no reason in them being member methods.

`LongAnswerText : IMeetingPollingQuestion`
This implementation looks out of place: why does Text implement Question? Judging by your full code, there is no reason in having this interface in the first place since it only has one implementation and you never call instances of that implementation by the interface.

---

In conclusion, most of the suggestions are aiming at making your solution less verbose: it will help a lot with readability and overall code clarity. There is a lot of extra logic which is not needed for the task you're trying to accomplish, get read of it and it will become much easier to implement stuff that you actually need.

Good luck with refactoring!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by member methods  can you explain

Comment: @Jefferson member or instance method is a method that works on a particular instance of a class. E.g. method `bark()` in `dog.bark()` would not make sense if you call it without a dog instance.

Comment: Thanks for the question about the interface if I wanted to use that what would I need to do?

Comment: @Jefferson sorry, what question?

Comment: The one about no reason in having this interface?

Comment: @Jefferson ah, you can just remove it since it serves no purpose.

Comment: What if I had another  controls like MultipleChoice would that have help

Comment: @Jefferson help what?

Comment: I was trying to use the factory pattern here, where the factory takes a MeetingPollingQuestionType and returns the UI/MVC appropriate

Comment: @Jefferson I don't see it in the code you provided.