# Dynamically MVC controls

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working project where I need to build ASP.net control based on JSON data. I am using the method below GetMeetingPollingQuestion to create this model.

**Any suggestions/comments are greatly appreciated to improve the code further. Thanks.**

JSON

```
[{"MeetingPollingQuestionId":1,"MeetingPollingQuestionType":"LongAnswerText","MeetingPollingId":1,"SequenceOrder":1,"MeetingPollingParts":[{"MeetingPollingPartsId":1,"Type":"Question","MeetingPollingQuestionId":1,"MeetingPollingPartsValues":[{"MeetingPollingPartsValuesId":1,"Type":"label","QuestionValue":"Do you have additional comments or concerns with these changes to the Guidelines?","FileManagerId":0,"FileName":null,"FileData":null,"FileType":null}]}]},{"MeetingPollingQuestionId":12,"MeetingPollingQuestionType":"MultipleChoice","MeetingPollingId":1,"SequenceOrder":2,"MeetingPollingParts":[{"MeetingPollingPartsId":35,"Type":"Question","MeetingPollingQuestionId":12,"MeetingPollingPartsValues":[{"MeetingPollingPartsValuesId":63,"Type":"label","QuestionValue":"Do you approve the following statement to be added for all current rituximab indications in the Guidelines: “An FDA-approved biosimilar is an appropriate substitute for rituximab”?  ","FileManagerId":0,"FileName":null,"FileData":null,"FileType":null}]},{"MeetingPollingPartsId":36,"Type":"Image","MeetingPollingQuestionId":12,"MeetingPollingPartsValues":[{"MeetingPollingPartsValuesId":64,"Type":"FileManagerId","QuestionValue":null,"FileManagerId":14716,"FileName":"B-cell_1.2022_panel vote_Page_02 - Copy.png","FileData":"iVBORw.....","FileType":"image/png"}]},{"MeetingPollingPartsId":37,"Type":"Answers","MeetingPollingQuestionId":12,"MeetingPollingPartsValues":[{"MeetingPollingPartsValuesId":65,"Type":"Answers","QuestionValue":"Yes","FileManagerId":0,"FileName":null,"FileData":null,"FileType":null},{"MeetingPollingPartsValuesId":66,"Type":"Answers","QuestionValue":"No","FileManagerId":0,"FileName":null,"FileData":null,"FileType":null},{"MeetingPollingPartsValuesId":67,"Type":"Answers","QuestionValue":"Abstain","FileManagerId":0,"FileName":null,"FileData":null,"FileType":null}]}]}]
```

Method

```
public IEnumerable<MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel> GetMeetingPollingQuestion()
{
    List<MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel> vm = new List<MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel>();
    //JSON Data parse into class Model and set to object ListofMeetingPollingQuestion
    foreach (MeetingPollingQuestion MeetingPollingQuestion in ListofMeetingPollingQuestion)
    {
        int SequenceOrder = MeetingPollingQuestion.SequenceOrder;
        switch (MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingQuestionType)
        {
           
            case "LongAnswerText":
                MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel LongAnswerText = new MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel();
                LongAnswerText.QuestionType = "LongAnswerText";
                var MeetingPollingParts = MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts;

                var LongAnswerQuestion = MeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Question");
                var labelControl = LongAnswerQuestion.MeetingPollingPartsValues.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "label");
                LongAnswerText.labelControl =  $"{SequenceOrder}. {labelControl.QuestionValue}'";
                LongAnswerText.textboxControl = $"textboxfor_{labelControl.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId}";
                vm.Add(LongAnswerText);
                break;

            case "MultipleChoice":
                MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel MultipleChoice = new MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel();
                MultipleChoice.QuestionType = "MultipleChoice";
                var MultipleChoiceMeetingPollingParts = MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts;

                var MultipleChoiceQuestion = MultipleChoiceMeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Question");
                var MultipleChoicelabelControl = MultipleChoiceQuestion.MeetingPollingPartsValues.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "label");
                MultipleChoice.labelControl = $"{SequenceOrder}. {MultipleChoicelabelControl.QuestionValue}'";

                var MultipleChoiceImage = MultipleChoiceMeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Image");
                var MultipleChoiceImageControl = MultipleChoiceImage.MeetingPollingPartsValues.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "FileManagerId");
                if (MultipleChoiceImageControl.FileManagerId != 0){
                    MultipleChoice.imageSRC = MultipleChoiceImageControl.FileData;
                }
                

                var MultipleChoiceAnswers = MultipleChoiceMeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Answers");
                var MultipleChoiceAnswersControl = MultipleChoiceAnswers.MeetingPollingPartsValues.ToList();

                List<CBRBControl> RadioButtonlist = new List<CBRBControl>();

                foreach (var item in MultipleChoiceAnswersControl)
                {
                    CBRBControl RadioButton = new CBRBControl();
                    RadioButton.Value = item.MeetingPollingPartsValuesId.ToString();
                    RadioButton.Label = item.QuestionValue;
                    RadioButtonlist.Add(RadioButton);
                }
                multipleChoice.RadioButtonName = $"radioList_{MultipleChoiceAnswers.MeetingPollingQuestionId}";
                multipleChoice.RadioButtonList = RadioButtonlist;
                vm.Add(MultipleChoice);
                break;
        }

    }

    return vm;



}
```

}

Model

```
public class  MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel
{
    public string QuestionType { get; set; }
    public string labelControl { get; set; }
    public string textboxControl { get; set; }
    public string imageControl { get; set; }
    public byte[] imageSRC { get; set; }
    public string RadioButtonName { get; set; }
    public List<CBRBControl> RadioButtonList { get; set; }
}


public class CBRBControl
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Properties need to be PascalCased. Local variables need to be camelCased.

Comment: Are you re-designing your code?  [I noted your previous, related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/280586/10221) with a `class LongAnswerText : IMeetingPollingQuestion` This is certainly relevant to any answers here.

Comment: I changed it to use FirstOrDefault but wanted to see if there is more refactoring that can be done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Gerneral advice

look at this line

```
List<MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel> vm = new List<MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel>();
```

this variable name `vm` showed be plural because it's a list `vms` .. and you can use the [simplified new expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0090)

```
List<MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel> vms = new();
```

your foreach loop could be more readable if you use `var` key word and short variable name

```
foreach (var Question in ListofMeetingPollingQuestion)
```

it's more readable than

```
foreach (MeetingPollingQuestion MeetingPollingQuestion in ListofMeetingPollingQuestion)
```

### Redundancy elimination

Looke at this of code for each case it's nearly identical

```
foreach (MeetingPollingQuestion MeetingPollingQuestion in ListofMeetingPollingQuestion)
{
    int SequenceOrder = MeetingPollingQuestion.SequenceOrder;
    switch (MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingQuestionType)
    {
        case "LongAnswerText":
            MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel LongAnswerText = new MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel();
            LongAnswerText.QuestionType = "LongAnswerText";
            var MeetingPollingParts = MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts;

            var LongAnswerQuestion = MeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Question");
            var labelControl = LongAnswerQuestion.MeetingPollingPartsValues.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "label");
            LongAnswerText.labelControl = $"{SequenceOrder}. {labelControl.QuestionValue}'";
            //... code
            vm.Add(LongAnswerText);
            break;

        case "MultipleChoice":
            MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel MultipleChoice = new MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel();
            MultipleChoice.QuestionType = "MultipleChoice";
            var MultipleChoiceMeetingPollingParts = MeetingPollingQuestion.MeetingPollingParts;

            var MultipleChoiceQuestion = MultipleChoiceMeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Question");
            var MultipleChoicelabelControl = MultipleChoiceQuestion.MeetingPollingPartsValues.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "label");
            MultipleChoice.labelControl = $"{SequenceOrder}. {MultipleChoicelabelControl.QuestionValue}'";
            //... code 
            vm.Add(MultipleChoice);
            break;
    }
}
```

in both cases you create a new view model and change the same property and create same variables with different names and at the end add this view model in your list

```
foreach (var Question in ListofMeetingPollingQuestion)
{
    int SequenceOrder = Question.SequenceOrder;

    MeetingPollingQuestionViewModel vm = new();
    vm.QuestionType = Question.MeetingPollingQuestionType;
    var MeetingPollingParts = Question.MeetingPollingParts;
    var QuestionObj = MeetingPollingParts.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "Question");
    var label = QuestionObj .MeetingPollingPartsValues.FirstOrDefault(part => part.Type == "label");
    vm.labelControl = $"{SequenceOrder}. {label.QuestionValue}'";

    switch (Question.MeetingPollingQuestionType)
    {
        case "LongAnswerText":
            //... code
            break;

        case "MultipleChoice":
            //... code
            break;
    }

    vms.Add(vm);
}
```

### Bad type

your code use string literals such as (`"LongAnswerText"`, `"MultipleChoice"`, `"FileManagerId"`, `"label"`,  `"Question"` ,... etc) you should avoid this technique because this string's value is not checked at compile time [Read more resons whe you should not use magic strings](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365344/404545) try useing Enums or constant value insted

for example define this enum

```
public enum QuestionType
{
    LongAnswerText,
    MultipleChoice
}
```

then change the type `MeetingPollingQuestionType` to be`QuestionType` then give your code the compiler check superpower as following

```
switch (Question.MeetingPollingQuestionType)
{
    case QuestionType.LongAnswerText:
        //... code
        break;

    case QuestionType.MultipleChoice:
        //... code
        break;
}
```